# CABasicAnimation swift not working

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation

I'm newly moving from obj C to swift, i'm not sure why it's not working because in obj c it's working fine, please take a look to my code

Here is my code

```
func addAnimationOnLayer( layer: CALayer, position: CGPoint, duration: TimeInterval, delay: TimeInterval, fromPosition: CGPoint, toPostion: CGPoint, key: String) {
        layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: position.x, y: position.y))
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0))
        }
        let theAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation")
        theAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        theAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        theAnimation.duration = duration
        theAnimation.beginTime = delay
        theAnimation.fromValue = fromPosition
        theAnimation.toValue = toPostion

        layer.add(theAnimation, forKey: key)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

and i call the function with this

```
self.addAnimationOnLayer(layer: self.logoImage.layer, position: CGPoint(x: 0, y:100), duration: 0.8, delay: 0.1, fromPosition: CGPoint(x: 0,y: 100), toPostion: CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), key: "logoStartAnimation")
```

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `CATransaction.begin()` try calling `CATransaction.flush()`.

Your code would then look like:

```
func addAnimationOnLayer( layer: CALayer, position: CGPoint, duration: TimeInterval, delay: TimeInterval, fromPosition: CGPoint, toPostion: CGPoint, key: String) {
    layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: position.x, y: position.y))
    CATransaction.flush()
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0))
    }
    let theAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation")
    theAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    theAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    theAnimation.duration = duration
    theAnimation.beginTime = delay
    theAnimation.fromValue = fromPosition
    theAnimation.toValue = toPostion

    layer.add(theAnimation, forKey: key)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Give that a try and let me know, I have had issues before with animations not happening because of bits of previous animations left over.

Comment: thanks for your help, it seems the animation is broken (moving fast/skipped).
even i try to remove the CATransaction stuff the animation still not working